# C#: Test if a class in an instance of a super class instead of a subclass

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class, which has a bunch of subclasses that inherit from it. How can I test to see whether an object is an instance of that super class, and not of any of the derived classes?

Example:

I have a Vehicle class, and it has several classes that inherit from it, like Car, Motorcycle, Bicycle, Truck, etc.

Assuming this, how do I test to see if a Vehicle object is really of the class Vehicle, and not Car or Bicycle? (Since a Car and a Bicycle are in this case an instance of the Vehicle class, too.)

Comment: It seems strange to me that Vehicle is not an abstract class. What is an example of an instance of Vehicle which is not any of the derived classes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if (theObject.GetType() == typeof(Vehicle))
{
   // it's really a Vehicle instance
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.GetType()` to determine the concrete type of the object.

```
Vehicle v = GetVehicle();

if(v.GetType() == typeof(Vehicle))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
bool isSuper = instance.GetType() == typeof(Vehicle);
```